# Microsoft fakes - shims without ShimsContext

Tags: .net, instrumentation, microsoft-fakes, shim

I'm trying to hook methods of an external .net program and the msft Fakes framework seems to make this very easy using Shims.

Here's an example:
Let's say a game uses a library that includes a chat class with an AddMessage(msg) method. I want to modify that Method in such a way a function of mine gets called with the argument. Then I could for example modify the msg and return the original function with my modified msg as the argument. 
Now the next time anything gets printed to the chat, my function would be executed and the modified string is displayed in the chatbox. 
I could just do that by modifying the IL asm of the dll itself, but that's not very sustainable for larger modifications or if the target updates.

My problem is that since fakes was only made to be used in a unit testing environment, shims only work in a ShimsContext - this is to prevent people from overriding methods outside of their testing cases, but that's exactly what I want to do.

Is it possible to 'globally' overwrite methods with shims or is the framework locked down in that regard?
If it's that locked down, are there any frameworks that might help me achieve my goal?